# Advanced Algoithm issues to generate unique 6 char long code

Tags: php, algorithm

I have used this algorithm to generate 100 codes. Now Once again i have searched the threads on this site and on google before posting. The algorthms found do work in generating the code the issue I got is i have to generate UNIQUE codes from the one i already have. The problem i am finding is all the scripts are all failing to execute.

So basically I have an ARRAY holding 100 voucher codes I need to generate 400 more voucher codes however while my algorithm's works it keeps timing out due to it taking to long to execute. I have tried several other algorithms from the threads on Stack overflow but for some reason they all keep timing out. I need advice on what I can do to my algorithm to actually produce 400 more unique 6 Char codes.

Here is script I have

```
/**
**Use this portion to get my current 100 codes in an array which i use
**/
$redeem = 'THIS IS A STRING WHICH CREATES AN ARRAY CONTIANING 100 VALUES'; 
$redeem = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $redeem);
$redeem_code = str_split($redeem, 6);

/**
**Function generates unique 6 letter voucher codes
**
**/

        function random_str($length, $keyspace = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
        {
            $str = '';
            $max = mb_strlen($keyspace, '8bit') - 1;
            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
            $str .= $keyspace[mt_rand(0, $max)];
            }
        return $str;
        }

/**
**This is the query which checks against my array and then echo's a valid code
**
**/
        $redeem_count = count($redeem_code);
        $i = 0;
        $ia = 1;
        while($i <= 500){

                $string = random_str(6);
                if(in_array($string, $redeem_code))
                {
                     echo $string;
                     $i= $i+1;
                }

        }
```

Constant Error Message on All functions tried.

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\nfr_chip.php on line 115
```

Comment: @StefanBeike, it's php if you look into the error :)

Comment: Well in_array probably returns false and the while loop never terminates. Try debugging...

Comment: You never add the generated code to the `$redeem_code` array so it will always be lest than 500.. forever and ever.

Comment: When creating a fully random string you always have a probability for collisions (even if they are low) so you'd have to retry until you get the number of unique codes you need (only use a very low percentage of the possible solution space to reduce collision probability) or add some non-random part, e.g. a sequence number etc. - Btw, please edit the tags accordingly, your question seems to be primarily based on php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never add anything to the array and only increase $i if the code already exist.

This should work...

```
$redeem_count = count($redeem_code);

while($redeem_count <= 500) {

   $string = random_str(6);
   if(!in_array($string, $redeem_code))
   {
        $redeem_code[] = $string;
        $redeem_count++;
   }

}
```

And for the way you are splitting your string with codes, instead of using `preg_replace` (avoid regex unless you really need it):

```
$redeem_code = explode(" ", $redeem);
```

Comment: Not sure I agree with the last part of your answer. IIRC explode only works on the string provided as a delimiter i.e. spaces only. The regex works on spaces, tabs, returns and other white space...

Comment: If you mix spaces, tabs and other white spaces as a delimiter in the same string, you have already messed up. Considering the example given, explode would be much better than first running a regex and then str_split().

Comment: I presume he's got a string containing series of 100 6 digit codes separated by white space. He should really use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) instead of the method he's chosen, but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` with `bin2hex` to generate pseudo-random, as the name implies, strings.

Here's an example:

```
for ($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
    print bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(3)) . PHP_EOL;
}

//output
9282fb
3b9798
c187a0
a058e3
df2e4b
```

3 bytes will give you a 6 char string